# Is it possible to color the opaque parts of a PNG with CSS only?

Tags: css, image, webkit

[image]

**Using CSS (webkit filters somehow?), is it possible to color the whole of a PNG image while maintaining the transparent background?**

The attached image is an example of what I'd like to achieve. The first PNG (dog on the left) is the 'untreated' PNG, the dog on the right is the PNG with the relevant CSS filters.

Note: I say 'filters' but if there is a different approach I'm happy to look into that.

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can make it black but not colored.

Comment: Black will do the trick, if you could provide that as answer that'd be great.

Comment: See below for quick "black" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to make the image black but not color it afterwards...as you can't "add" color to grey.

Support: Chrome 18 (prefix), FF35, Opera (prefix), Safari 6 (prefix).

See compatability chart [**@ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(0) brightness(0);
  filter: contrast(0) brightness(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/dog-clipart-puppy_dog_with_bone.png" alt="">
```

Comment: That's spot on. Thanks very much.